# Bind ChartType to button click

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to bind the chartType of a graph to a button click event in Visual studio. So When the corresponding button is clicked, the chart will change to the type indicated; but, as of yet, it's not doing anything. So far my C# for the problem looks like this:

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        String ddlValueX, ddlValueY;
        enum SeriesChartType
        {
            Pie,
            Bar,
            Graph
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Manually regiseter the event-handling method for the click event
            btnPie.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnPie_Click);
            btnBar.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnBar_Click);
            btnGraph.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnGraph_Click);
        }

        public void btnPie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType)(SeriesChartType.Pie);
            Chart1.DataBind();
        }

        public void btnBar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType)(SeriesChartType.Bar);
            Chart1.DataBind();
        }

        public void btnGraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType)(SeriesChartType.Graph);
            Chart1.DataBind();
        }
```

I was hoping that this would bind the chart to the specified type on buttonClick, but it doesn't seem to be having an effect on the page. I was getting an incompatible type error until I tried to cast like this:

```
(System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType)(SeriesChartType.Graph);
```

Honestly, i'm not confident that that's correct, but I don't know what else to do.

The HTML for the affected parts are as follows:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="Main" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
            <div id="Profile" style="height: 100%; width: 18%; float: left;">
                <div id="profilePicture" style="padding-bottom: 10%;">
                    <img alt="" src="profile_picture_by_ralucs_stock-d6jc4xg.jpg" style="width: 80%;" />
                </div>
                <div id="profileInfo" style="padding-bottom: 10%;">
                    <h5>Username</h5>
                    <h5>Interests</h5>
                </div>
                <div id="messageBox">
                    <h5>TBA</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Body" style="height: 100%; width:80%; float: right;">
                <div id="button">
                    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ScriptManager>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnPie" OnClick="btnPie_Click" runat="server" Text="Pie" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnBar" OnClick="btnBar_Click" runat="server" Text="Bar" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnGraph" OnClick="btnGraph_Click" runat="server" Text="Graph" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUserInfo1"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUserInfo1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Please Make a Selection" Value="0" />
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Gender</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Location</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Guild</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="4">Material</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="5">Type</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="6">Quantity</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUserInfo2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUserInfo3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUserInfo3_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Please Make a Selection" Value="0" />
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Age Bracket</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Product Cost</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Quantity Sold</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUserInfo4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlUserInfo1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
                <div id="chart">
                    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="569px" DataSourceID="Database1">
                        <Series>
                            <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="GuildTypeName" YValueMembers="ProductCost">
                            </asp:Series>
                        </Series>
                        <ChartAreas>
                            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                            </asp:ChartArea>
                        </ChartAreas>
                    </asp:Chart>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Database1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Stats]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I'm fairly new to both C# and HTML so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'll bet the problem is that you created your own `SeriesChartType` enum instead of just using `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType`. Just add the line `using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;` above your class definition, remove the custom enum, and there's no need to cast your types.

Comment: Also, it's not necessary to specify your click handlers twice. You can eliminate your `PageLoad` handler entirely and just rely on your `OnClick` attribute in the ASP file.

Comment: remove the enum, remove the handlers in page_load. you will be fine like this `this.Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I made the changes, but it's still not updating when I click the buttons. I think it's probably something to do with postback though. How do I upvote?